# Convert beautiful HTML/CSS template to PDF report

Tags: html, css, pdf, report, mailmerge

I have a beautiful HTML/CSS template that I would like to convert to a PDF

Amongst the many challenges I have encountered - I would like to retain all the CSS styling and also the page should break at specific parts so that the report does not look malformatted.

I am using Python to dynamically generate the HTML/CSS page based on some database inputs which are then inserted into the HTML/CSS template to generate the report.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I have tried online solutions but they seem rubbish and do not honor HTMl/CSS also I have tried various Python libraries which have mostly been crappy for the same reasons.

Comment: @KJ you are awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Do you have any solutions for page break? so that Chrome PDF respects when the page should break because right now it breaks the page wherever it wants and sometimes HTML doesnt look correct because it goes on two pages.

Comment: Have you had a look at [paged.js](https://pagedjs.org)?

Answer (score -2):

Use that: https://html2pdf.com/de/
Also for CSS
Search before you ask something

Comment: Hi new contributor. Re-read my question again. I've already used this service and a few like it, and they do not retain the formatting of the original HTML.